# Fluid 960 Grid System with 24 columns or more?

Tags: css, 960.gs

is there a way of having at least 24 columns using Fluid 960 Grid System?

http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/

cause i want a fluid version and im currently using the fluid version you can download with css generator on 960:s website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do the math 960/24 = 40 so yes but you might need to work out the css yourself though - I am not familiar with this css library. If you know how the fluid grid system works. My favourite article on the subject is by Jon Tan and this should tell you everything you need to know: http://jontangerine.com/log/2007/09/the-incredible-em-and-elastic-layouts-with-css

Answer (score 3):

give a try to [fluid24.org](http://fluid24.org) it is based on 960.gs but allows you a fluid/liquid layout

Comment: Works great, and it's compatible with the existing fluid 960 for 12 and 16 columns